# Problems with Events Not Appearing in GA4 Custom Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm facing a frustrating problem with GA4 custom reports and would like to know if anyone here can help me.

**Background:**

I have performed the standard implementation of the events and run the debugging tests. The events are tracked normally during the test, but do not appear in my GA4 custom reports for certain periods.

**What I've tried:**

- Debugging tests - Searching StackOverflow - Checking settings

Unfortunately, none of this solved my problem.

**Event details:**

The events in question track the flow of an online hire that I manage. It's like a conversion funnel. All completed hires are stored in a separate database.

**Problem period:**

From 04/09/2023 to 11/09/2023, I had hires that should have triggered the "summary-hire" event, but that specific event doesn't appear in GA4's custom reports.

**Comparison with UA:**

In Universal Analytics (UA), these events were tracked and reported correctly. It seems that something is wrong with GA4, or the way it tracks events is very different and confusing.

**Attachments:**

- [PRINT 1]: Print of event configuration
  https://prnt.sc/GiblbKiF57vG
- [PRINT 2]: Printout of the hires table in my database
  https://prnt.sc/Kzl2wwpW0nac
  https://prnt.sc/gnoYYwbB9meZ
- [PRINT 3]: Print with explanatory comments on the discrepancy
  https://prnt.sc/xobvh3LFaMUF

I'm really baffled by this situation and would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you!